# CMake generated VS project expecting lib instead of dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmake

Here is my minimal example of below: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fwsr3sigb60rtw/leveling-test.zip?dl=0

My current project folder structure and relevant CMakeLists content:

```
leveling
├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(deps) 
└── deps
    ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(xml-reading)
    └── xml-reading
        ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(deps)
        │                   add_library(xml-reading ...)
        │                   target_include_directories(xml-reading PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/tinyxml2)
        │                   target_link_libraries(xml-reading PUBLIC tinyxml2)
        └── deps
            ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(tinyxml2)
            └── tinyxml2
```

this generates a xml-reading.dll file.

But then the leveling project linker options have `/DYNAMICBASE "bin\windows-32\debug\xml-reading.lib" "bin\windows-32\debug\BOBPrimitives.lib" "bin\windows-32\debug\tinyxml2d.lib"`

Which yields:
`2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bin\windows-32\debug\xml-reading.lib'`

What's up?

- I tried adding SHARED to `add_library(xml-reading SHARED ...)`, didn't help
- As a workaround I set STATIC at `add_library(xml-reading STATIC ...)` to force it to produce a .lib file - **but I'd like to understand what's going on**

Comment: add_library defaults to SHARED libraries (creating a dll and a lib file) setting STATIC causes it to create an archive library (creating a lib file).  If xml-reading is only header files then I would image that no library is actually created because there is no source code to compile.  Did xml-reading actually build and create a file?

Comment: For this question I added an empty cpp file to xml-reading so a file is indeed created, a dll file when STATIC is not specified in add_library

Comment: added minimal example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fwsr3sigb60rtw/leveling-test.zip?dl=0

Comment: also created a CMake bug report https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18684

Comment: Should not Shared projects create both a .lib and a .dll files? (this .lib is for devs linking with your .dll)

Comment: Specific Windows thing - ```set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)``` does the trick.

Comment: Note: `target_include_directories(xml-reading PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/tinyxml2)` shouldn't be necessary if you `target_link_libraries(xml-reading PUBLIC tinyxml2)` and tinyxml2 is set up right.